# Set flex columns per row with dynamic number of items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can have dynamic amount of child items. I mean 1, 5 or 150 etc in flex container.
How can I set them to be exactly `25%` of `flex-basis` so that if I have only 3 items in wrapper: they are still looking like 4 columns, but one is empty.

Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/ybjvtuqg/

```
<p>
  first example
</p>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>


<p>
  second example
</p>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

& style:

```
.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #cecece;

  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #16B6B6FF;
}
```

As you can see - in first example it looks like every child takes 33% of width, while I would like to be 25%, and have an empty col in the end with 25% (without changing HTML and do any hardcode).

In the second example: it's the same - on second row items take 50% - that is not correct. Every item should take exactly 25% and leave free space if any...

Is it possible with flex?

Comment: remove `flex: 1 0 25%;` instead add `.item { width: 25%; max-width: 25%; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.items {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #cecece;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 4px;
  background: #16B6B6FF;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(25% - 8px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way `flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 8px);` `8px` its `margin`

```
.item {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 8px);
  margin: 4px;
  background: #16B6B6FF;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/1uhcL76f/5/

Answer (score 0):

The first solution I just came up with is to change `flex-grow` to 0 and `flex-basis` to `calc(25% - 8px)`.

As follows:

```
flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 8px);
```

You have to subtract `8px` because its a sum  of `margin-left` and `margin-right`.

The second solution could be:

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item__wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__wrapper">
    <div class="item">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__wrapper">
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__wrapper">
    <div class="item">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item__wrapper">
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.item__wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 4px;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.item {
  height: 100%;
  background: #16B6B6FF;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't split examples - child are dynamic (I mean their count)